# JSON to array of objects, and adding item to each object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to retrieve data from a JSON file and creating an array of objects (works fine), but I also want to add an item to each object in the array while doing so.

This is my code:

```
var linklist = [];
$.getJSON('links.json').success(function (json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, obj) {
            linklist.push(obj);
            $(obj).extend({
                status:'Downloaded'
            });
        });
        })
```

If I try to output data in status, I get `'undefined'` as a value.

Comment: I think you want `$.extend(obj, { status: "Downloaded" });`

Comment: Still learning, and guess I was closer than I thought! Thanks! Feel free to add an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: You don't need the `$.extend`: `obj.status = 'Downloaded';` Also note that Ajax is _Asynchronous_.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
var linklist = [];
$.getJSON('links.json').success(function (json) {
    $.each(json, function(i, obj) {

        // add status property to current object
        obj.status = 'Downloaded';

        // add updated object to array
        linklist.push(obj)

    });
});
```